# Normal Distribution and a Discrete Amount

Tags: normal-distribution

From what I understand about normal distribution is that you make a discrete number continuous by adding .5 which every way the question asks for.

What if you were to have a discrete number with a set amount you cannot have half of. 
Would you keep it discrete?

Ex) say there were 30 prizes, would you calculate the z-score as 30 or 30.5?

If a game was attempted 100 times and the chance of winning is 30%, would 30 prizes be enough?

mean= np = 100*.2=20

standard deviation sqrt(100*0.2*0.8) = 16

Here is my dilemma:

z(30) 
=(30-20)/16 
=10/16 
=0.63

0.63=0.7357

z(30.5)
=(30.5-20)/16
=10.5/16
=0.66

0.66=0.7454
SO, the chances of having enough prizes for 100 attempts is either 73.57 or 74.54 depending on that 0.5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose we have a binomially distributed random variable $X$, and we want to use the normal approximation. If "$n$" is quite big, say $1500$, the continuity correction makes no big difference, so it is of no great practical importance whether or not you use it. (But if an exercise *wants* you to use it, you have no choice.)

For middling $n$, such as $n=50$, the continuity correction often yields a more accurate approximation. Here is how I would apply it.

**Method:** Let $k$ be an **integer**. Then $\Pr(X\le k)$ gets approximated by the probability that the normal with the same mean $np$ and same variance $np(1-p)$ as $X$ is $\le k+0.5$. This latter probability is the same as the probability that $Z\le \frac{k+0.5-np}{\sqrt{np(1-p)}}$.

A similar continuity correction is made when we approximate a Poisson with not too small $\lambda$ by a normal. But the main place where you will be using the continuity correction is in the normal approximation to the Binomial.

**A Caution:** We do not automatically "add $0.5$."  Here is an example. Use the normal approximation with continuity correction to approximate the probability that $X\lt k$, where $k$ is a given integer.

At first sight this looks like the approximation problem described under **Method.** But there is a difference, here we have $\lt k$, not $\le k$. So here is what we do. The probability that $X\lt k$ is exactly the same as the probability that $X\le k-1$. Now this looks exactly like the kind of problem discussed in Method, we have a $\le$.

So the required probability is approximated by the probability that a certain normal is $\le k-1+0.5$, in other words by the probability the normal is $\le k-0.5$.

So when you are using the continuity correction with the binomial, I would advise making sure to convert the problem into one that involves $\le$.

As another example, suppose we want to approximate the probability that $X\ge k$. Be careful in applying the continuity correction. We want $1$ minus the  probability that $X\lt k)$. The $X\lt k$ problem has been just discussed.

I hope this short description has been helpful.

**Remark:** For the places where continuity correction can be helpful, it is less important than it used to be. For using software we can calculate binomial probabilities **exactly**.

About the prizes question, I can answer it properly only if I get the full *exact* statement of the problem.

Comment: I believe I am understanding it a bit more, it would seem as though you would have k-0.5 because it includes equals to. Greatly appreciate the response.

Comment: Roughly speaking it is because the probability that $X=k$ is better approximated by the probability that the normal is between $k+0.5$ and $k-0.5$ than by the probability that the normal is between $k-1$ and $k$.